# Testing travis-ci on ruby file returns rake aborted error

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

Inspired by Travis CI's [guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners) for complete beginner, I wanted to test Travis on my preferred language: Ruby.

I created a similar repo like [Travis' sample PHP repo](https://github.com/plaindocs/travis-broken-example). [Here](https://github.com/IggHub/travis-broken-ruby) is my attempt to make my own Travis repo test.

Inside that repo, I have a `.travis.yml` file containing:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2
  - jruby
```

And a ruby file that I wish to run with invalid method in it:

```
def sum
  return "1" + 1
end

sum
```

However, when I push it, it returns this error:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

When I went back to read the travis [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/) for ruby, there is a line that says:

> Travis CI runs rake by default to execute your tests. Please note that
>   you need to add rake to your Gemfile (adding it to the :test group
>   should be sufficient).

What does that mean? What else do I have to add to my repo and `.travis.yml` to have a "successful" failing test? Ok, my last question sounds like a paradox, but essentially I want to know how I can test Travis CI with ruby by creating a failed test and creating a successful test like the said [PHP test](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners) earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travis is basically just a computer like any other. What it says is that by default, it will run `rake` in that repo assuming that's where the tests are.

And indeed, if you were to clone your own repo and run `rake` yourself, you'd get the same output you're reporting.

So either you provide another command to run to Travis, or install a test that will run when `rake` is invoked (in your Rakefile, probably).

Also to note that your "Ruby file" doesn't really contain a test per se, just some code. Usually a test will assert things such as `assert_equal(2, sum)` or `expect(sum).to eq(2)` if you were to use Rspec. You can look up "ruby test frameworks" if you need more info about that.

Comment: Thanks! I have been reading more about rake. I tested it on one of my rails projects and it passed. Although I still have more to learn about Travis, I have a much clearer idea than what I had before. Thank you so much!